# How to get preprocess/postprocess steps from model created using Google Vertex AI?

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, tensorrt, google-cloud-vertex-ai

A client of mine wants to run their Google Vertex AI model on NVIDIA Jetson boards using TensorRT as accelerator. The problem with this is that their model uses certain operators (DecodeJpeg) that are not supported by ONNX. I've been able to isolate the feature extrator subgraph from the model, so everything supported by ONNX is being used, while the preprocess and postprocess will be written separate from the model.

I'm asking because I need to be provided the pre/postprocess of the model so I could implement them separately, so is there a way to get pre/postprocess from Google Vertex AI console?

I've tried running a loop that rescales the image to a squared tile from 0 to 512, but none of those gave the adequate result.

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz I haven't tried much since I don't have access to the Vertex AI console, I need to find a solution and provide it to the client so they can provide me the info I need.

Comment: Does this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/add-preprocessing-functions-tensorflow-models-and-deploy-vertex-ai) help you?

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand the question, but if it is "I am using standard models in Vertex AI, can I get the code used inside", then I am pretty sure the answer is “no“.